# Create a process from a driver

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, internals

Is there a way to create a user-mode process from kernel-mode on Windows NT platform (XP-W7)?

EDIT: I must install only the driver. This is a specific of the project.

Comment: I am thinking about injecting a thread with my own user-mode code to some user proceess from the driver...

Comment: Look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/KernelExec.aspx. Interesting...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a valid win32 process the driver must communicate with CSRSS (what is completely undocumented). So I ended up by queuing a user-mode APC and allocating virtual memory for the APC code in the context of the existing win32 process (that code will call CreateProcess and do the job).

It is a tricky way but it works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know an easier way to achieve this. But what about having a Windows service running which makes an overlapped DeviceIoControl into your driver? On return the service could examine the data it has received from the driver and start the according application.

Comment: I would say this is the correct solution.  Issue a reverse IRP from a service, let the driver complete when it needs the user-mode process to begin.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I cannot have my service running (If only the service will be installed and started from kernel-mode).

Comment: @Sergius: You have to install the driver anyway. You could install the service using the same INF file.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be directly done - Creating a win32 process requires some set up by the user mode part of CreateProcess, not just creating the process object in kernel mode.

You need some user mode code here - either a service, a desktop app, or so on, to launch the your user mode application.